# Base Virtual Method not called or called twice

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, virtual, method-hiding

Here my code.

```
public class EventItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = -1;
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public EventItem(IDataRecord rdr)
    {
        FillAttributs(rdr);
    }

    public virtual void FillAttributs(IDataRecord rdr)
    {
        this.Id = (int)rdr["EventId"];
        this.ClientId = (int)rdr["ClientId"];
    }
}

public class ControlItem : EventItem
{
    public int ControlId { get; set; }

    public ControlItem(IDataRecord rdr) : base(rdr)
    {
        FillAttributs(rdr);
    }

    public override void FillAttributs(IDataRecord rdr)
    {
        base.FillAttributs(rdr); // Version 1
        this.ControlId = (int)rdr["ControlId"];
    }
}
...
ControlItem ctrl = new ControlItem(rdr)
```

**Version 1** : With `base.FillAttributs(rdr)`, `FillAttributs` of base class and child class are called twice. Without, only `FillAttributs` of child class is called twice.

**Version 2** : I remove `base.FillAttributs(rdr)`, `virtual` and replace `override` with `public new void FillAttributs(IDataRecord rdr)`. So It works but I'm not sure if it's a good practice.

**Version 3** : I rename `FillAttributs` of base class to `FillEventAttributs` and of chil class to `FillControlAttributs`.

what is the right way to go here ? Or should I use another way to do it ?

Comment: The reason behind this is the constructor. When you create object of `ControlItem`, base constructor is called first then constructor of `ControlItem` is called. They both call `FillAttributs` method that's why you see them being called twice.

Comment: They are called twice because you have a call FillAttributes() in the constructor of each. If you want to only call it once then leave it out of the constructor and fill them as needed.

Comment: That depends on what functionality you want when someone calls `FillAttributes` from outside of the classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove FillAttributs(rdr) from ControlItem constructor.
its look like this:

```
public class EventItem
{
public int Id { get; set; } = -1;
public int ClientId { get; set; }

public EventItem(IDataRecord rdr)
{
    FillAttributs(rdr);
}

public virtual void FillAttributs(IDataRecord rdr)
{
    this.Id = (int)rdr["EventId"];
    this.ClientId = (int)rdr["ClientId"];
}
}

public class ControlItem : EventItem
{
public int ControlId { get; set; }

public ControlItem(IDataRecord rdr) : base(rdr)
{
    //FillAttributs(rdr);
}

public override void FillAttributs(IDataRecord rdr)
{
    base.FillAttributs(rdr); // Version 1
    this.ControlId = (int)rdr["ControlId"];
}
}
...
ControlItem ctrl = new ControlItem(rdr)
```

Now base and derived called once.
I hope this help you.